# Group Isomorphism and proofs

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

(I just followed the instructions on Mathjex but why didn't the typeset work?) Please don't report my question as a duplicate, similar questions exist, however, I want someone to help me with my question, to help with my solution.

Q) If  $\phi: G \to H$ is a group Isomorphism, then define: $\phi^{-1}: H \to G$ such that $\phi^{-1}(b) = a$ if $\phi (a) = b$ is an isomorphism.

Sol)  I have shown that $\phi^{-1}$ is injective as well as a homomorphism, I intend to show that it is surjective. For that, I argue that since $\text{im}(\phi)$ is $H$, then for each $b$ in $H$ we have a unique $a$ in $G$ such that $\phi (a) = b$, now by definition $\phi^{-1}(b)=a$ such that $b$ is also unique if $b$ is not unique, then  $\phi$ is not a valid function, now what do I do after this?  (I always have had problems with proofs (struggling for the last 3-4 months )). How do I show that from my argument it follows that $\phi^{-1}$ is surjective ?

Comment: You need to put `$` signs around all the text you want to be considered as MathJax. `$\Phi: G \to H$` gives $\Phi: G \to H$.

Comment: Put your superscripts in braces: `$\Phi^{-1}$` gives $\Phi^{-1}$ instead of `$\Phi^-1$` which gives $\Phi^-1$.

Comment: Thank you for investing your precious time.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof ends (or should end) at the moment that you write that $\varphi^{-1}(b)=a$. The element $a$ of $G$ is an arbitrary element of $G$ and what you wrote proves that there is a $b\in H$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(b)=a$. Therefore, $\varphi^{-1}$ is surjective. And this has **nothing** to do with groups or with group homomorphisms.